# C# - Transfer the text of a hyperlink through a session inside a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, session

I want to transfer the text of a hyperlink through a session inside a repeater. But I can not think of the logic to do this. My repeater generates links within that dropdown menu and I want to get the text that appears in the link and pass it to another page `Sectors.aspx`. This is what I have done so far:

--- edit ---

I want that when the link is clicked, the text that is in the link is passed to the other page. For example, the menu has two links, APPLE and BANANA. When the user clicks APPLE, I want the next page `Sectors.aspx` to know that the user clicked APPLE and not the other options.

**ASPX Page:**

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Setor</button>
            <div class="dropdown_content">
                <asp:Repeater ID="sectors_menu" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink id="hyperlink1" NavigateUrl="Sectors.aspx" Text='<%#((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["sector"] %>' runat="server"></asp:HyperLink> 
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </div>
        </div>

</asp:Content>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        MySqlConnection mysql_connection = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
        string mysql_string;
        MySqlDataAdapter mysql_data_adapter;

        public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Sector_label();
        }

        public void Sector_label()
        {
            mysql_string = "SELECT * FROM employees GROUP BY sector";
            mysql_data_adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(mysql_string, mysql_connection);

            DataTable data_table = new DataTable();
            mysql_data_adapter.Fill(data_table);
            DataView data_view = new DataView(data_table);

            sectors_menu.DataSource = data_view;
            sectors_menu.DataBind();

            for (int count = 0; count < sectors_menu.Items.Count; count++)
            {
                var test = (HyperLink)sectors_menu.Items[count].FindControl("hyperlink1");

                Session["session_hyperlink"] = test.Text;

                // Debug.WriteLine(test.Text);
            }   
        }
    }
```

Comment: you want to get `sector` field's text from `data_view ` but you try to get it from repeater's hyperlink . why you don't loop `data_table` and get it from there instead ?

Comment: @zey I edited my post. I think it's clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the text as a parameter of the `NavigateUrl`:

```xml
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink id="hyperlink1" NavigateUrl='<%# "Sectors.aspx?sector=" + Server.UrlEncode(((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["sector"]).ToString() %>' Text='<%#((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["sector"] %>' runat="server"></asp:HyperLink> 
</ItemTemplate>
```

Then, `Sectors.aspx` can retrieve it through the "sector" parameter:

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sector = Request.Params["sector"];
}
```

That `id="hyperlink1"` parameter looks fishy, though.  You don't want all your hyperlinks to have the same ID.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `hyperlink` tag with this code ,

```
   <asp:HyperLink runat="server" Navigateurl='<%#"Sectors.aspx?mySector="+ Eval("sector") %>'   
                    Text='<%#((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["sector"] %>' />
```